# I want to place the edges of a Hamiltonian cycle

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

I don't understand why, but the `GraphLayout` style "CircularEmbedding" doesn't place the vertices/edges of a Hamiltonian cycle on the circle. Is there any way I can force it to do this? I haven't been able to find an answer online, so any help would be appreciated.

For reference, I'm trying to produce images of some cages where a Hamiltonian cycle is placed on the circle.

Comment: `IGraphM` might have a solution

Answer (score 3):

As of Mathematica 11.3, `GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"` will place the vertices around a circle in the same order as they appear in `VertexList[graph]`.

Thus, you need to reorder the vertices according to the Hamiltonian cycle.

Example:

```
g = GraphData["DodecahedralGraph"];

Graph[
 FindHamiltonianCycle[g][[1, All, 1]],
 EdgeList[g],
 GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"
]
```

[image]

Now that 12.0 is out in the cloud, it is good to mention that 12.0 requires

```
GraphLayout -> {"CircularEmbedding", "OptimalOrder" -> False}
```

In 12.0, vertices are reordered by "CircularEmbedding" to obtain a nicer layout with fewer crossing edges. `"OptimalOrder" -> False` disabled this reordering so that we can use our own order (in this case the Hamiltonian cycle).

---

The [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) way of doing it is the following, if you prefer it:

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]
IGLayoutCircle@IGReorderVertices[FindHamiltonianCycle[g][[1, All, 1]], g]
```

[image]

`IGReorderVertices` will preserve graph properties (including styling) when reordering vertices.